# Identify this cartoon in which Batman races Flash

Tags: story-identification, dc

I just stumbled upon this awesome video on YouTube:

Which TV series, movie this video clip is from?

Comment: Downvoted for a complete and total lack of research effort. **It literally says the name of the series at the start of the clip**.

Comment: @Valorum there are two movies in that category: Batman unlimited Animal instincts and Batman unlimited Monster Mayhem. And I don't remember seeing this clip in either of them.

Comment: Link is now dead...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Batman Unlimited: Some Assembly Required](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6102480/?ref_=ttep_ep5)

> Batman and Robin test interchangeable parts of their vehicles, the Batmobile and the Batjet, on a course. Flash, Nightwing and Green Arrow assist.